# NSPersistentStoreCoordinator Crash

Tags: iphone, core-data, xcode4, ios5

I recently updated from xcode 3.x to 4.2 and I am having issues with core data when I run apps in 4.2. I also updated to iOS 5 so maybe the issue is in there, I'm not really sure.

The apps ran fine in 3.x but crash in 4.2.  The issue occurs whenever I tried to access a `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` object.  Here is an example of an area where the app crashes.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]    URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"GraffitiMap.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}
```

It cashes at the line: `persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];`

What am I missing about transitioning an app from xcode 3.x to 4.2, or upgrading to iOS 5?

Comment: What error do you get in the console when the crash happens? Also, try assigning `[self managedObjectModel]` to an intermediate variable so that you can see what you get there.

Answer (score 1):

I met with this problem before after I upgraded to Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5.

My app was keeping crash on `[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];` with error `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`, I did a lot of tests to investigate where the problem is. Finally after I deleted all fetch requests in data model, the error gone and said another error "the entity name not found". So I was trying to delete fetch request one by one, and test again and again to figure out which is that "bad" fetch request. And I found that there are two fetch requests do same thing (have same criteria on same entity) although they have different name, than I deleted one of them, the error was fixed completely.

Today I meet with this problem again, and I'm sure that there is no duplicate fetch request this time, but the error still remain. I thought apple add some validations on CoreData like this in new iOS5, but can not find any docs which describe this.

Hope this help you

Comment: Am having the same issue - however, I don't want to/can't just delete my fetch requests - I'm using them! Any further ideas on this.

Comment: If you are using two requests which do same thing exactly, why not delete one of them. Or maybe you can add some criteria for one of the request just like "1=1" to make them different.